# My test skips when i pass more than one argument to @test annotation in testNg

Tags: testng

I am trying to pass more than one argument to @Test annotation in testNG and testcase skips.......

@Test(dependsOnMethods = {"vvvvv"},dataProvider="getData")

Can some one help me as how do I pass more than one argument to test annotation..

Answer (score 0):

Having more than one argument for `@org.testng.annotations.Test` by itself does not make tests being skipped.

Consider the following class:

```
public class Test1 {

@DataProvider(name = "getData")
public Iterator<Object[]> provideInts() {
    List<Object[]> list = new ArrayList<Object[]>();
    list.add(new Integer[]{0,1});
    list.add(new Integer[]{1,1});
    list.add(new Integer[]{1,2});

    return list.iterator();

}

@Test
public void vvvvv() {
    Reporter.log("vvvvv",true);
    Assert.assertTrue(true);
}

@Test(dependsOnMethods = {"vvvvv"},dataProvider="getData")
public void testStuff(Integer param0, Integer param1) {
    Reporter.log("testStuff: " + param0 + ", " + param1 , true);
    Assert.assertTrue(true);
}
}
```

(I used the annotation text from the question).

It provided the below output (totally as expected):

```
vvvvv
testStuff: 0, 1
testStuff: 1, 1
testStuff: 1, 2
Tests run: 4, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.395 sec
```

(Maven 3.0.5, default setup, testng 6.8).

So, the issue is elsewhere. Suspects: junit.Test annotation used; the 'vvvvv' is not made a test method or failed. Please paste more code and settings if it doesn't help.

Comment: Thanks for your Reply Patrungel.... Test execute fine with one parameter in @test annotation and the same skips when i pass 2 parameters...

Comment: Public class LoginTest(){@Test(dataProvider="getData")
 public void SuccessfulLoginTest(Hashtable<String,String> data){if( !TestUtil.isExecutable("LoginTest", Pages.xls1))
throw new SkipException("The RunMode is set to NO for loginTest");
if(!data.get("ValidCredentials").equals("Y"))
throw new SkipException("The RunMode is set to NO for datset");
boolean testDataType=true;
LoginPage<WebDriver> lp = new LoginPage<WebDriver>();
lp.SuccesfulLogin(data.get("Username"),data.get("Password"));
if (testDataType & lp!=null ){
Assert.assertTrue(true, "Could succesfully login");Pages.isloggedin=true;
}
}

Comment: @Test(dataProvider="getData")
 public void UnsuccessfulLoginTest(Hashtable<String,String> data){
  
   
  if( !TestUtil.isExecutable("LoginTest", Pages.xls1))
   throw new SkipException("The RunMode is set to NO for loginTest");
  
    
  if(!data.get("ValidCredentials").equals("N"))
   throw new SkipException("The RunMode is set to NO for datset");
  
  LoginPage<WebDriver> UL = new LoginPage<WebDriver>();
  UL.UnsuccesfulLogin(data.get("Username"),data.get("Password"));
  
  
  }
 
 @DataProvider
 public Object[][] getData(){
  return TestUtil.getData("LoginTest", Pages.xls1);
 }
 
 
   
 }

Comment: Out put:
===============================================
Default suite
Total tests run: 3, Failures: 0, Skips: 2
===============================================

Comment: So far no multiple parameters for any of the methods in the code pasted. (Also 'Public class LoginTest()' thing looks odd but I suppose it's just some typo).
Unless the condition for throwing SkipException comes true, these test methods should pass. The skips you could have with that code occur when the condition fails, and that's likely what you want (if xls data says the login is good, skip the negative test, otherwise skip the positive one).
What is the second parameter that you are adding?